# How to calculate percentage with a SQL Server statement?

Tags: sql-server, count, percentage

[I want to add a column for the percentage of **COUNT_COUNTRY** values, how to do that in SQL server?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txraT.png)

[image]

Comment: please avoid posting image. Post as text. Also include your requirement, computation formula etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the percentage value by dividing with the total count.

try the following:

```
select top 5 country, Count(country) as COUNT_COUNTRY, cast(count(country)*100.0/(select count(1) from Sales) as numeric(5,2)) as [%age]
from Sales
group by country
order by COUNT_COUNTRY desc
```